# Create a snippet in VS code that expands BLOCK_COMMENT_START certain times

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I was looking to create `n` times the `BLOCK_COMMENT_START` in a line in my code.
The `BLOCK_COMMENT_START` for language `perl` is `#`.

I want to create a line such as this:

`####################`

which contains **`n`** `BLOCK_COMMENT_START` in a line (in this case `20`).

It can be any `n` times though, for instance where `"editor.wordWrapColumn": 80`, I want `80` times.

How to create such snippet in vs code.

The thing that I did was:

```
"Commented line": {
        "scope": "perl",
        "prefix": "coml",
        "body": [
            "BLOCK_COMMENT_START" // repeat it 20 times
        ],
        "description": "Single line comment"
    }
```

How to modify this snippet so it does the job?

Comment: what's so hard about it? is it not just `"$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START$BLOCK_COMMENT_START"` ?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it, but I was looking for variable expansion or more **elegant** option. It may be `20` times or `30` or any `n` times.

Comment: Do your perl comments have a space after the `#`, like `# `?

Comment: Yes. It looks better for readability.

Comment: Okay, that makes it a little trickier to work with but can still be done.  I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want by simply using the built-in snippets.  I think an extension could do it - and still use a snippet.

Here is a way to do it using keybindings and an extension I wrote, [Repeat Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.repeat-commands).  Try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+r",                     // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "repeat-commands.runSequence",
  "args": {

    "description": "repeat perl comment character",
    
    "preCommands": [
      "cursorHome",
      "editor.action.commentLine",          // add a comment
      "cursorLeft",                         // if you have a space after the '#'
      "cursorColumnSelectLeft"              // select the '#'
    ],
    
    "commands": [                          // these will be repeated
      "editor.action.duplicateSelection"
    ],

                                           // one comment character already added above
    // "repeat": 5,                        // you can hard-code a number
    "repeat": "${getRepeatInput}",         // or ask for a number input
  },

    "when": "editorLangId === perl"
},
```

[image: repeat comment characters with extension demo]